# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to get a number of users excluding the logged in user. But I get this error when running the query, what are my missing?

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except()

```
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $tests = $this->user->where('referrer', $user)
                  ->except($user)
                  ->orderBy('id')
                  ->take(2)
                   ->get();


    // $this->user was already injected in the constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `whereNotIn`instead of `except()` as I do not think `except()` is a method of the query builder or has been deprecated.

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;

$tests = $this->user->where('referrer', $user)
              ->whereNotIn('id', [$user])
              ->orderBy('id')
              ->take(2)
               ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses